# Grails - Duplicate form submission handling - How does withForm{} works ?

Tags: forms, grails, duplicates, form-submit

I am trying to handle duplicate form submission in my Grails app. So I set `useToken="true"` in my form, and this is how I try to use the `withForm` method in my controller:

```
def myControllerAction {
    withForm {
       *my action's logic*
    }
}
```

However, I end-up with: `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.` in my browser. 
So I guess I am not using it right, and I have not found any example on the web on how to use the method properly.

Any help on this would be very helpful. 
Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really have much in your example: the short answer is that you must be doing something to cause redirects if the token is invalid.

The [Grails Manual](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#formtokens) shows how to use it.

All the logic does is put a hidden field with a unique value in it.  That value is stored in the session, so your sessions must be working correctly (and you need session affinity or shared session if hosting in a clustered environment).  When the form is submitted, it looks for that unique value, and determines if it's already been submitted or not.

You don't appear to be handling an `invalidToken` anywhere, so you might be dealing with a situation where the token isn't being stored or passed correctly, and your logic is causing a redirect.  If you are redirecting using a `get` instead of a `post`, this could be causing a redirect loop.  (This may cause a redirect loop even if the token is processed *correctly* the first time.)

I would look at your code and figure out where the redirect is coming from.  It isn't caused by the token directly.

Comment: Thanks a ton ! 
My action was handling both "POST" and "GET" methods. I took the "GET" part out of the "withForm" scope and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the question - '**duplicate** form submission ', you have **two** requests being sent to the server, so you have to deal with **both** of them.

So, two identical requests are sent from the browser to the server, and so the action will be invoked twice.

The first request will succeed, and use the code in the 'withForm' block, and the token will be incremented.

The second request still contains the same token as the first request, but the server has thrown that token away, so the second request uses the code in the 'invalidToken' block, or a default block if you've omitted your 'invalidToken' block.

One important point is that - it is the second (bad) request that will dictate what is shown on the browser, since it arrives after the first, so I have decided , in handling the bad request, to redirect the user back to the index, where they should be able to see the record that was created and saved by the first request.
i.e.

```
     }.invalidToken 
 {
    println "myController: swallowing request with invalidToken (probably a double-click or due to using back button in browser.)"
    flash.invalidToken = " " // just enough to trigger the g:if in the index.gsp
    redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
 }
```

and then in the index.gsp, I show a message:

```
<g:if test="${flash.invalidToken}">
<ul class="errors" role="alert">
<li>
    <g:message code="error.doubleclick" 
           default="oops, the item you are creating exists already (maybe you double-clicked on the 'Save' button ?).  Click on the item in the list below to continue working with that item."
/>
</li>
</ul>
```

This works OK, and is general enough that you can cut n paste into any controller, and index.gsp, without having to customise it.